Why Did LOCK-prefixed Instructions Become Preferred Over MFENCE for Memory Fences in the JVM on x86?
Context
This question explores the semantics of the MFENCE full memory barrier instruction in the x86 instruction set, particularly in comparison with modifying instructions that include the LOCK prefix.
Historically, the MFENCE instruction was used in the JVM to implement memory ordering guarantees, such as those required for the volatile keyword. However, a significant shift occurred in the late 2000s. In David Dice’s blog post from May 2009, he described a transition to using LOCK-prefixed instructions, such as LOCK:ADD to the top of stack (TOS), citing superior performance.
Dice noted that on modern AMD processors at the time, LOCK:ADD demonstrated nearly twice the latency improvement over MFENCE. Similarly, on Intel processors, LOCK:ADD performed better within the instruction pipeline. These observations motivated JVM developers to switch to LOCK-prefixed instructions for implementing memory fences, particularly in the context of volatile.
This shift is intriguing because LOCK-prefixed modifying instructions theoretically perform additional work compared to the streamlined MFENCE, such as enforcing atomicity. One might expect this to make LOCK-prefixed instructions less efficient. Dice speculated that MFENCE might carry additional, less-visible semantics—possibly related to pipeline states or inter-core synchronization—leading to its relatively lower performance. However, the exact nature of this potential "hidden semantics" remains unclear.
Moreover, LOCK-prefixed instructions provide added flexibility. They can serve as both memory fences and atomic operations, making them highly optimized for various workloads on modern CPUs.

Key Questions

Does the LOCK prefix fully encompass the semantics of MFENCE, or does it only address reordering prevention?
Does MFENCE include additional "hidden" semantics beyond its documented behavior, such as implications for pipeline management or cross-core synchronization?
Why did LOCK-prefixed instructions surpass MFENCE in performance over time, despite their seemingly broader functionality?

I’d greatly appreciate detailed insights into these questions, particularly from those familiar with low-level architecture and microcode optimizations. Thank you in advance!

My answer on Why does C#'s Thread.MemoryBarrier() use "lock or" instead of mfence? actually cites several links about why Java switched, says basically nothing about C#, and answers basically all your questions (including 1 and 2).  For (3), mfence might always have been slower, but JVM devs didn't realize it right away.

@PeterCordes Indeed, it's very interesting! It is possible that the JVM developers were initially unaware of the additional semantics of MFENCE, and as hardware evolved, the differences between the instructions became more pronounced, which had a noticeable impact on performance. It's one of those paradoxical cases where reality somewhat contradicts straightforward logic.

It's also possible that mfence was as fast or faster on old CPUs like Pentium 4 where it was new with SSE2.  Or maybe not; JVMs and other software had been using dummy lock add or lock or instructions as full barriers on CPUs older than P4 which didn't have mfence.

@PeterCordes Well, if I understood the context of this question correctly and accurately perceived the information provided by David, then earlier the base instruction for ensuring memory barrier semantics was mfence. It is also true that mfence did not appear immediately but came with the SSE2 instruction set. What was used before that? Most likely, it was the same lock, but I cannot say for sure as I don’t have reliable information. On older processors, mfence indeed worked well and even demonstrated better performance in comparative tests.

@PeterCordes What’s interesting is that, over time, the situation shifted in favor of lock in terms of performance. This is quite intriguing because it implies that architectural changes occurred in processors themselves, making them process lock more efficiently than mfence. I also speculated that lock might simply be better optimized, given that it historically appeared much earlier and continues to be widely used. I assumed it might have better optimization at the microcode level.

@PeterCordes Interestingly, David mentioned that the best solution would be to switch to lock xchg instead of lock add, as xchg does not cause undesirable side effects such as resetting integer condition codes.

xchg modifies an integer register; that sucks much more than writing FLAGS for scheduling other instructions around it.  (xchg is good for a seq_cst store, though, vs. mov plus a barrier).  Most x86 instructions write FLAGS, so you already can't usually keep a FLAGS result alive for long; not at all a big deal to pick lock add which clobbers it and doesn't actually modify memory.  (I assume that or some other no-op (except for FLAGS) locked instruction was the barrier of choice in x86 JVMs before mfence existed.  xchg on some unallocated stack memory is possible, though.)

@PeterCordes Yes, most likely lock add, as other implementations were seemingly not used and only discussed. I think this is why they moved away from xchg, as it’s not as efficient due to the nuances you mentioned. If the situation hasn’t changed since the late 2000s, this is indeed the case.
